# Describing qualitatively the level sets of the function $f(x, y) = x^3 - x$

Tags: curves

I have to describe the behaviour, while $c$ is changing, of the level curve $f(x,y)=c$ for the function $f(x,y)=x^3-x$.

I have done the following:

The level curves are defined by $$\{(x,y)\mid x^3-x=c\}$$

For $c=0$ we have that the set consists of the lines $x=0,x=1,x=-1$.

Is it correct so far?

How could we continue? What can we say about the other values if $c$? Which is the set when $c$ is positive and which when $c$ is negative?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

According to Travis' answer we have that any level set $\{f(x, y) = c\}$ is a union of the vertical lines $\{x = x_0\}$ in the plane, where $x_0$ varies over the roots of $f(x, y) -c = x^3 - x + c$.

Since this is a cubic polynomial, depending on the value of $c$ it can have three real single roots, one real single root and one real double root, or one real single root and two nonreal roots.

$$$$

Why do we describe in that way the behaviour of the level curve?

When the polynomial has three roots does the level curve consist of three lines?

What happens when the polynomial has a double root?

And what happens when it has non-real roots?

$$$$

Also what information do we get for the graph of $f$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x, y)$ depends only on $x$, so if $(x_0, y_0)$ is on the level curve, so is $(x_0, y)$ for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, any level set $\{f(x, y) = c\}$ is a union of the vertical lines $\{x = x_0\}$ in the plane, where $x_0$ varies over the roots of $$f(x, y) = x^3 - x - c$$ regarded as a function of $x$ alone. Since this is a cubic polynomial in $x$, depending on the value of $c$ it can have three real single roots, one real single root and one real double root, or one real single root and two nonreal roots.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-) @Travis

Comment: @MaryStar You're welcome, I hope you found it useful!

Comment: I read again your answer... Why do we describe in that way the behaviour of the level curve? When the polynomial has three roots does the level curve consist of three lines? What happens when the polynomial has a double root? And what happens when it has non-real roots? $$$$ Also what information do we get for the graph of $f$ ?

Comment: Yes, when the polynomial $x^3 - x - c$ has three roots, say, $r_1, r_2, r_3$, then all of the points $(r_i, y)$, $i \in \{1, 2, 3\}$, $y \in \Bbb R$ are solutions, and so this level set is three (parallel) lines.

Comment: (NB I've corrected a sign error in my answer.)

Comment: Ah ok... And when the polynomial $x^3-x-c$ has one simple real root and one double real root? Is then the level set two lines?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $\!$

Comment: Ah ok... And when the polynomial $x^3-x-c$ has one real root and two non-real roots? Is then the level set one line?

Comment: Yes, that's right, in general you can adjust my statement for the three-separate-roots case by replacing the list $r_1, r_2, r_3$ of roots with the list of (real) roots.